# On the subset of a closed vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Theorem: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $U$ and $V$ be closed subspaces of $H$ such that $U\subset V$. Then there exists a nonzero vector $v\in V\backslash U$ such that $v\bot U$.

- The fact that $v$ exists follows directly from the definition of $V$ and $U$.
- The fact that $v$ is nonzero comes from the fact that $0\in U\cap V$ so $0\not\in V\backslash U$.
- All that remains is to show $\langle v,u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$.

What's the best way to start my proof from here? I could say that $\langle v,u\rangle$ needs to equal $0$, and that $v=v_1+v_2$ with $v_1\in U$ and $v_2\in V$, but following that path gets me needing to show that $\langle v_1,u\rangle=0$ and I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental result about Hilbert spaces is that the orthogonal projection along closed subspaces exist. So, denote by $P_U\colon H\to H$ the orthogonal projection along $U$. If $v\in V\setminus U$, what can you say about $v-P_U(v)$?

Note that the hypothesis that $V$ is closed is redundant.